# How do you avoid duplicate entry into database?

Tags: python, mysql

I would like to filter database inserts to avoid duplicates so it only insert 1 product per 1 `ProductId`. How do I do this?
This is my insert:

```
add_data = ("INSERT INTO productdetails"
            "(productId, productUrl, discount, evaluateScore, volume, packageType, lotNum, validTime, storeName, storeUrl, allImageUrls, description) "
            "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
```

This is how it suppose to look like but in PyMySQL, how do I do the same in mysql.connector ?

```
INSERT INTO producttable (productId, productTitle, salePrice, originalPrice )
        SELECT * FROM (SELECT %(productId)s, %(productTitle)s, %(salePrice)s, %(originalPrice)s) AS tmp
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT productId FROM producttable WHERE productId = %(productId)s
        )
        LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Add a `UNIQUE` constraint on the column in the database itself…!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set column to unique. then use INSERT IGNORE statement, If there is duplicate entry the query will not execute. you can read more [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm) about INSERT IGNORE.

Answer (score 2):

The proper approach to do this is at the database end. You need to add a unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE productdetails
ADD UNIQUE (productId);
```

You can than simply do Insert, without any  where or if.

Why? 
If you keep a set as suggested by yayati, you will limit yourself by having the set and the processing surrounding it as a bottleneck.

If you add the constraint, than it's left to the database to do fast checks for uniqueness even with millions of rows. Than you see if the DB returns error if its not unique.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create the Insert statements via the String Interpolation in and keep adding them in a Set. The Set collection would only keep unique strings in itself. You can then bulk load the Set of unique SQL insert statements into your RDBMS.

Comment: how do you add WHERE NOT EXISTS like the sample I added above ?

Comment: Have you looked at this library in Python https://www.sqlalchemy.org/. SQLAlchemy is specifically designed to handle relational database interactions in Python. You can get the necessary ORMs for your case